# CSS Hyperlink with text below image using span tag not working

Tags: css, html

I am creating thumbnail with hyperlink image and text below it and on mousehover div content should display, so far mousehover is working fine, as i am not good at CSS. I am not able to get the text below image using span.
please also see the reference at www.ge.com on right hand side of the page under under "SEE MORE stories", which i want to replicate it on my website, please help.

```
                <a href="" class="nav-holder-link">
                <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
                <span class="nav-holder-text">moving</span>
                <div class="nav-holder-preview">
                    <img width="305" height="100" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p style="position:absolute;top:55px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">Powered by GE locomotives, the Juice Train is bringing Orange Juice to your breakfast table in one of the most efficient ways possible.</p>
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="" class="nav-holder-link">
                <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img2.jpg" alt=""/>
                <span class="nav-holder-text">Watch</span>
                <div class="nav-holder-preview">
                    <img width="305" height="100" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <p style="position:absolute;top:55px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">Watch this time lapse as the Tropicana/CSX Juice Train, powered by two 4,400 HP GE </p>
                </div>
                </a>
```

Comment: Block level elements such as a div inside an inline element such as an anchor tag is malformed HTML. Inline elements should only contain inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this???

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/vbscript">
' <!--
Function ToggleInformationOn(Id)
    if Id = 1 then
        ToggleInformationOff()
        window.document.getElementById("info4image1").style.display = "block"
    elseif Id = 2 then
        ToggleInformationOff()
        window.document.getElementById("info4image2").style.display = "block"
    elseif Id = 3 then
        ToggleInformationOff()
        window.document.getElementById("info4image3").style.display = "block"
    elseif Id = 4 then
        ToggleInformationOff()
        window.document.getElementById("info4image4").style.display = "block"
    end if
End Function

Function ToggleInformationOff()
    window.document.getElementById("info4image1").style.display = "none"
    window.document.getElementById("info4image2").style.display = "none"
    window.document.getElementById("info4image3").style.display = "none"
    window.document.getElementById("info4image4").style.display = "none"
End Function
' -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div style="width: 305px;">
        <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">
            <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(1)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()" /><br />
            <span class="nav-holder-text" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(1)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()">moving</span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">
            <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(2)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()" /><br />
            <span class="nav-holder-text" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(1)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()">Watch</span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">
            <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(3)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()" /><br />
            <span class="nav-holder-text" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(1)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()">Charley</span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">
            <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(4)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()" /><br />
            <span class="nav-holder-text" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(1)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()">Football</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="info4image1" class="nav-holder-preview"  style="position: absolute; width: 305px; top: 75px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
        <img width="305" height="100" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
        <p style="width: 305px">Powered by GE locomotives, the Juice Train is bringing Orange Juice to your breakfast table in one of the most efficient ways possible.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="info4image2" class="nav-holder-preview"  style="position: absolute; width: 305px; top: 75px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
        <img width="305" height="100" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" />
        <p style="width: 305px">Watch this time lapse as the Tropicana/CSX Juice Train, powered by two 4,400 HP GE </p>
    </div>
    <div id="info4image3" class="nav-holder-preview"  style="position: absolute; width: 305px; top: 75px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
        <img width="305" height="100" src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
        <p style="width: 305px">Powered by willy wonka's choclate factory, blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="info4image4" class="nav-holder-preview"  style="position: absolute; width: 305px; top: 75px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; display: none;">
        <img width="305" height="100" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" />
        <p style="width: 305px">Watch manchester united play football then have a beer and think about how nice life is when you support a superb football team</p>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans, but I want Hyper link with Image and text below and horizontally aligned, which has hidden div in it on mousehover it should display, the mouse over part I have done, but I am not able to make text below image and aligned them horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You can place your link inside each of the hidden div's... 
something along the lines of...

```
<div style="width: 25%; float: left;">
  <a hef="link-to-somepage.aspx">
    <img width="67" height="51" class="nav-header-image" src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(4)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()" /><br />
        <span class="nav-holder-text" onmouseover="ToggleInformationOn(1)" onmouseout="ToggleInformationOff()">Football</span>
  </a>
</div>
```